# How do I create slideshows for Youtube videos?

Tags: views

[Like this website](http://www.tseries.com/), I want to make a slideshow of you tube videos as done in LATEST VIDEOS section.

In order to achieve this:

1. I created a **view of content type Video** (in my case), added the field which has the **video in the field's section**.
2. To have the same videos as **pager**, I added the **video field in the pager**. But there is no option to **resize the video** to a smaller size so that it can be used as a pager.
3. And lastly, videos are also not getting displayed as expected in case of **"SLIDESHOW"**  formatter, **vertical** list of videos is getting displayed.

Answer (score 1):

Follow these steps

1. Install and enable these four modules:[

   [CTools](http://drupal.org/project/ctools)
    [Views](http://drupal.org/project/views)
    [Views Slideshow](http://drupal.org/project/views_slideshow)
    [Libraries](http://drupal.org/project/libraries)

You're also going to need a single file that contains a JQuery slideshow script. This will need to be uploaded manually.

Visit [link](http://malsup.com/jquery/cycle)
Click the Download the Cycle Plugin link. It's hard to spot so i had highlighted it on the image below:

[image]

Download the file which will be called jquery.cycle.all.js
Access your site files.
Browse to the /sites/all/ folder.
Create a folder called /libraries/ so that the path is /sites/all/libraries/
Create a folder called /jquery.cycle/ so that the path is /sites/all/libraries//jquery.cycle/
Upload the jquery.cycle.all.js file into that last folder.

[image]

Step 2: Views

We're going to create our slideshow using Views.

Go to Structure > Views > Add new view.
Check Create a block
Choose Slideshow for the Display format
Choose 1 for the Items per page

Click Add.
Select video.
Click Apply (All displays).

Check the box which says Exclude from display.
Click Apply (All displays).

Find the Format area on the left-hand side of the Views page.
Click Settings next to Slideshow.

Scroll down to the cycle options.
Click Apply (All displays).

Comment: Oops! Google Chrome could not connect to malsup.com

Comment: check permision for js files folder